# Controller does not exist error

Tags: php, laravel

I get controller does not exist error.

These are the code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class videosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $videos = DB::table('videos')->get();
        return view('index', ['videos' => $videos]);
        //return View:make('index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/',array('uses' => 'videosController@index'));
```

Comment: Route::get('/','videosController@index'); try this instead of Route::get('/',array('uses' => 'videosController@index'));

Comment: i tried it, not working too

Comment: Is your filename videoscontroller?

Comment: Yes, that's the name of the videocontroller.

Comment: you've videos in the above code.

Comment: yes, it is all videos..the file name is videosController too

Comment: this is the name of the controller. videosController.php

Comment: @user1688346 public function index()
{
    echo "test"
} try this ,instead of use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; use " use DB;"

Comment: I think you are using Resource Controller so your route should be `Route::resource('/','videosController');`

Answer (score 1):

this works perfectly.
    Route::get('/',[
    'uses' => 'videosController@index',
    'as' => 'index'

]);

Answer (score 1):

believe your problem is in relation to the file name. Linux vs Windows name case sensitive, please look the name.

After look:

php artisan dump-autoload  or composer dump-autoload